# how to create custom url

Tags: php, url

how to create custom url with httaccess
my code is

```
 localhost/site::Detail::OID::12::post title
```

1=site is my root folder

2=Detail is define word for detail product

3=OID define word for offer id

4=12 is number of offer

5=post title is title of offer

Comment: That is a bizarre url structure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should take a look to this :

https://www.addedbytes.com/articles/for-beginners/url-rewriting-for-beginners/

URL Rewriting allows you to modify URL.

EDIT :

Try with this :

```
RewriteEngine 
RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*)$ /$1::$2 [L,R=301]
```

Comment: how to add :: to url ?

Comment: Take a look to my previous message

Comment: `RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*)$ test.php /$1::$2 [L,R=301]`  not working for me`http://localhost/takhfif::Detail::1`